# Redactor.js List editing causes Chrome to crash, cpu goes to 100%

Tags: google-chrome, contenteditable, redactor, execcommand

We are using [Redactor.js](http://imperavi.com/redactor/) as a rich text editor.

Admittedly, we are using it on a rather complex webpage, but we have everything working fine, except...

### Steps to reproduce

(1) selecting all three of these items inside of a redactor contenteditable div:

- item 1
- item 2

  item 3

(2) select to convert the three items into a unordered list. On redactor's website it converts the items to:

item 1

item 2

- item 3

On our site, the Chrome tab becomes unresponsive and cpu usage goes to 100%, yet Chrome never officially close or crashes the tab. Tab remains until you force quit the process.

### What happens in the JS code

Inside the redactor.js source (version 10.0.2) the unordered list handler calls the list toggle function on line 4232. As that function runs, it determines that a list needs added and a list needs removed (line 4251). It then runs the list remove function (line 4356) which runs:

```
document.execCommand('insert' + cmd);
```

the variable cmd equals the string "unorderedlist" and Chrome stops working (on our site, not on redactor's website).

### What are the differences?

Changes to the redactor configuration seem to have no effect on the issue. None the less, here is our redactor.js config object:

```
 $this.redactor({
       allowedTags: ['a', 'abbr', 'acronym', 'address', 'article', 'aside', 'b', 'big', 'blockquote', 'br', 'button', 'caption', 'center', 'cite', 'code', 'col', 'colgroup', 'dd', 'del', 'div', 'dl', 'dt', 'em', 'fieldset', 'font', 'footer', 'form', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'header', 'hgroup', 'i', 'img', 'label', 'legend', 'li', 'marquee', 'ol', 'option', 'p', 'pre', 'q', 's', 'samp', 'section', 'select', 'small', 'span', 'strike', 'strong', 'sub', 'sup', 'table', 'tbody', 'td', 'textarea', 'tfoot', 'th', 'thead', 'time', 'tr', 'tt', 'u', 'ul', 'var', 'wbr'], 
        buttons: ['formatting', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'orderedlist', 'unorderedlist', 'outdent', 'indent'],
        cleanOnPaste: true, 
        clipboardImageUpload: false, 
        dragImageUpload: false, 
        dragFileUpload: false, 
        formatting: ['p', 'h1', 'blockquote', 'pre'],
        imageEditable: false, 
        imageLink: false, 
        imagePosition: false, 
        imageResizable: false, 
        linkTooltip: true,
        placeholder: self.config.placeholder,
        removeAttr:  [
          ['blockquote', 'class'],
          ['h1', 'class'],
          ['ol', 'class'],
          ['p', 'class'],
          ['ul', 'class']
        ],
        removeComments: true, 
        removeDataAttr: true, 
        removeEmpty: ['blockquote', 'em', 'h1', 'ol', 'p', 'pre', 'span', 'strong', 'ul'],
        replaceTags: [
          ['big', 'strong'],
          ['strike', 'del']
        ],
        tabKey: true,
        toolbarExternal: '#mceTextTools' + index,
        blurCallback: function(e) {
        },
        changeCallback: function() {
        },
        clickCallback: function(e) {
        },
        focusCallback: function(e) {
        },
        keyupCallback: function(e) {
        },
        pasteCallback: function(html) {
        },
        pasteBeforeCallback: function(html) {
        },
        modalOpenedCallback: function (name, modal) {
        },
        initCallback: function() {
        }
      });
```

Also, we have some suspicion that the problem may be due to some specific CSS rule that does not react well to document.execCommand. Here are the computed styles we are using on s.

```
ul {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
    cursor: auto;
    display: block;
    font-family: Georgia, Cambria, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32.4000015258789px;
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: 688px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
li {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
    display: list-item;
    font-family: Georgia, Cambria, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32.4000015258789px;
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 648px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Any ideas would be very much appreciated!

Comment: the error only happens in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution we can find is to add this to the beginning of the list toggle function (line 4235):

```
var test = this.selection.getNodes();
_.each(test, function(v){
    if (v.tagName === 'BR'){
        this.selection.selectElement(this.selection.getBlocks()[0]);
    }
});
```

The problem appears to be with this.selection.getCurrent(). Sometimes when BRs are present in the selection, getCurrent() does not return a proper document node. Resetting the selection with the code above prevents Chrome from crashing, but also slightly changes the behavor of the ordered/unorderd list buttons.

Comment: Line numbers change from version to version so it would be helpful to know what version you are referring to. Also, what is the actual name of "the list toggle function"?

Comment: I think I found it. Searching for `list: function()` and just below you'll find the toggle function (line 6353 in 10.2.5)

Answer (score 0):

This is the response from Redactor's support:

Thanks for reaching out. Unfortunately, I'm unable to reproduce the issue at http://imperavi.com/redactor. I suspect there may be some sort of conflict somewhere in your code.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hello, just ran into this problem myself. Would love to see a better response to this. I can replicate on your websites redactor instance by removing the <br> tag at the end of each li.

Ordered or undordered list format is: `<ul><li>text<br></li>...</ul>` Removing this br will cause chrome to crash (other browsers not tested). 

My instance of redactor does not add those <br>'s and I have no idea why not. Please let me know if you guys can help.

Comment: I just reproduced the issue in Imperavi's 10.2.5 distribution as is. They no longer support this version but I've asked them to make an exception, seen as how they failed to reproduce it themselves back when they did support it. Here is a screencast of steps we use to reproduce the issue
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9831841/redactor_bug_list_item_pin.mp4